# Getting all values from Foreach loop and placing them in a comma separated array in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, foreach

Ok this is probably really simple and I just can not figure it out! I need to grab the value from an array in foreach loop in php and pass it into an array fro jquery. Here is my code:

```
foreach ($results as &$value) {
            $vall[] = $value.", ";
        }   
        $result = count($results);
        echo $result;
        print_r($vall);
```

This prints out a normal array = Array ( [0] => one.jpg, [1] => two.jpg, [2] => three.JPG, [3] => four.JPG, )

I need it to create an array like this: one.jpg, two.jpg, three.JPG, four.JPG (only the values) Then I need to pass that to my jquery:

```
$(".next").click(function(){
            var p = [<?php echo $vall ?>];
            var start = id;
            var next = p[($.inArray(start, p) + 1) % p.length];
            var prev = p[($.inArray(start, p) - 1 + p.length) % p.length];
            $(".cont").append(next);
            $(".cont").append(prev);
            });
```

**I also need to take the comma off of last value.. any help or alternatives to get this done would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $vall = implode(', ',$results);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not take the far simpler route and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

Replace this...

```
[<?php echo $vall ?>]
```

with this....

```
<?php echo json_encode($results); ?>
```

and you can get rid of your entire foreach loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to render the array for use in JavaScript and you are using PHP 5.2.0 or later, you can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

If you just want to print out the array in the format you describe but don't need to worry about escaping special characters for JavaScript, you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).